# OpenGL Texture Blending

Tags: javascript, java, webgl, alpha, teavm

I have made a WebGL port of Minecraft Classic 0.30 Survival Test using TeaVM and I'm having some issues with WebGL texture blending.

Here is the code I'm using:

```java
if(textureName.equals("/terrain.png") || textureName.equals("/arrow.png")) {
    GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_BLEND);
    GL11.glBlendFunc(GL11.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL11.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
}
```

Here is the result:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/SpRg3.png

Do I have to use any GLSL or is there a way I can do it without it?

Edit: Here is the [source code](https://github.com/PeytonPlayz595/Shadow-Client-Classic) if anybody wants to look at it.

Comment: looks like your depth testing is broken?

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by doing this:

```java
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
glAlphaFunc(GL_LESS, 1.0F);
```